# Run gdb command from shell script

Tags: bash, shell, gdb, breakpoints

I was just wondering if it is possible to pass command to GDB from shell script.
I will just demonstrate it in code, so it is easier to understand.

```
#!/bin/sh
gdb --silent Application.app
b -[Class method]
```

This causes the execution of the script to stop at line 2, and continue only when I quit GDB.
 How would I pass the command, if it is even possible? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gdb` has an option to run the commands from a file with option `--command=FILE`. You can write all the gdb commands inside that `FILE`.