# Run gdb command from within shell script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gdb, coredump

I am making a simple coredump analyzer. I have a core file and symbols. Now I want to create a utility so these 2 files can be uploaded, and it shows the stacktrace (bt).
I execute a shell script which does:

```
gzip -d coredump.gz
tar xvf symbols.tar.gz
gdb program
#Now at this point I want to send gdb commands one at a time. Like:
core-file corefile
echo bt
```

I want to save the output of "bt" to a file. How can I do that?

Comment: For sending commands, check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863025/run-gdb-command-from-shell-script
For the latter part of you question, you could [log the gdb output](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Logging-Output.html).

Answer (score 2):

You want:

```
rm -f gdb.txt
gdb -ex 'set logging on' -ex 'where' program corefile
# GDB output is now in gdb.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, that works if I add it to the shell script. But if I call it from php shell_exec, it doesn't work. I asked another seperate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48715364/run-gdb-batch-from-shell-script-through-shell-exec-in-php. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I called `disassemble fn` using the method, above. But it seems that when there are multiple function with the same name in the binary file, only one is disassembled. Is it possible to disassemble all of them or I should disassemble them based on raw address?