# Run gdb batch from shell script through shell_exec in php

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gdb, coredump

Ok, I have a php calling a shell script:

```
shell_exec("sh /home/u-pc/Downloads/coredumps/analyze.sh");
```

In the shell script (analyze.sh) I have:

```
...# Other setup code...
gzip -d coredump.gz
tar xvg symbols.gz
gdb -batch -ex "set logging on" -ex "bt" myprogram mycoredump -ex "set logging off"
```

Now php is able to execute the shell script but only until untar of symbols. It doesn't seem to run the gdb command. I get no stacktrace log file.

Interesting thing is, when I run the analyze.sh by itself, everything works fine and gdb.txt is created with the "bt" output. Any ideas?

Comment: `shell_exec("sh /home/u-pc/Downloads/coredumps/analyze.sh >/tmp/log 2>/tmp/log2");` See what errors show up.

Comment: /home/u-pc/Downloads/coredumps/analyze.sh: 23: /home/u-pc/Downloads/coredumps/analyze.sh: ~/gdb-7.7/gdb/gdb: not found

Comment: Thanks so much!! needed absolute path instead of ~/gdb-7.7/gdb/gdb